# How can we access list item's column value on the master page?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I believe we can use JavaScript object model or the user control.

Basically we want to fetch the loggedin user name, then query a custom list to get the corresponding item value (boolean) and decide to redirect or not.

Which method will be good practice.?

Comment: Which method to do what, the redirection?

Comment: Fetch list item value and depending on the boolean value redirect.

Comment: Well, try it and see what happens...

Comment: Try what, what are you trying to say. I know that both are possible solutions, want advice on best practice..

Answer (score 1):

You can have a query like that

```
function retrieveListItems(siteUrl) {
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Announcements');

var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
camlQuery.set_viewXml(
    '<View><Query><Where><Geq><FieldRef Name=\'ID\'/>' + 
    '<Value Type=\'Number\'>1</Value></Geq></Where></Query>' + 
    '<RowLimit>10</RowLimit></View>'
);
this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);

clientContext.load(collListItem);
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
    Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), 
    Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed)
);
}

function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {
    var listItemInfo = '';
    var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();


while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
    var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
    listItemInfo += '\nID: ' + oListItem.get_id() + 
        '\nTitle: ' + oListItem.get_item('Title') + 
        '\nBody: ' + oListItem.get_item('Body');
}

alert(listItemInfo.toString());
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + 
        '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

Then instead to have the while process you can check the value that u looking at and do a **window.location.replace(...)** if you need

Comment: this techniques is the javascript object model right?

Comment: Do you believe this is better than a solution using an usercontrol?

Comment: are you working on SP2013 or 2010?

Comment: Sp2013 so cross site scripting is possible.

Comment: yep in this case I suggest to u to use js csom

Answer (score 0):

You can use a delegate control. So you don't need to modify the master page.

> All of the out-of-box SharePoint master pages include the
>   following in the HEAD section of the HTML markup:
>
> ```
> <SharePoint:DelegateControl runat="server" 
>           ControlId="AdditionalPageHead" 
>           AllowMultipleControls="true"/>
> ```
>
> The DelegateControl provides a plugin framework for SharePoint,
>   telling ASP.NET to find any registered delegate controls, and for each
>   call the LoadControl method to load your control.  It’s a very slick
>   way to add controls to pages without modifying the master page.

See this for more information: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2011/04/06/adding-jquery-to-every-page-in-sharepoint-with-delegate-controls.aspx